# Powershell - Export all both empty and non-empty groups in Active Directory

Tags: powershell

Now just I am able to export all ad groups with members. My question is : I am stuck trying to figure out how to export Active Directory groups that are don't have members well.

```
$result = Get-ADGroup -Properties Name -Filter 'name -like "*VPN*"' | ForEach-Object { 
    $group = $_.Name
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | 
    Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'user'} |
    Get-ADUser -Properties Displayname,Name,EmailAddress |
    Select-Object @{Name = 'Group'; Expression = {$group}}, Displayname,Name,EmailAddress

$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\tmp\Groups.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way this could be done is with a simple alteration. You can check if your query has a result before piping to `Select-Object`.

```
$result = Get-ADGroup -Properties Name -Filter 'name -like "*VPN*"' | ForEach-Object { 
    $group = $_.Name
    $query = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | 
        Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'user'} |
        Get-ADUser -Properties Displayname,Name,EmailAddress
    if (!$query) {
        [pscustomobject]"" | Select-Object @{Name = 'Group'; Expression = {$group}}, Displayname,Name,EmailAddress
    }
    else {
        $query | Select-Object @{Name = 'Group'; Expression = {$group}}, Displayname,Name,EmailAddress
    }
}
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\tmp\Groups.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

The other option would be to create a custom object during each iteration and build it accordingly. You can then set values for properties that will actually have values.